# Google+ multiple accounts issue on Android while sharing post

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I've integrated Google+ successfully in my Android application by following the Google's tutorial at: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

The problem I'm facing is with multiple accounts configured on my device, say Account **A** and **B**. The Google+ app ion my phone is configured with **Account A**.

Now, when I tap on Login button in my app, account selection dialog appears. I select **Account B**. APp successfully logs in with this account and I'm able to get user's information like name, dp etc.

But when I try to share a post on google+, the sharing dialog appears and it strangely has 
**Account A** set on top. *(Sharing it also appears in feed on Account A rather than B.)*

I'm using following code for sharing:

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
      .setType("text/plain")
      .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
      .getIntent();

startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Just saw another question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457420/sign-in-and-share-on-google-using-the-google-platform-for-android-multiple-u

The answer says:
_Currently this is the only way to use Google+ for Android with multiple Google accounts. There is nothing you can do about this until Google adds full account support to the app._

Is this answer still valid?